# list.remove() isn't removing all instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm facing rather bizarre situation with lists. It appears that Python is very selective about what zeros it will remove in this case:

```
count = 0
a = ["a",0,0,"b",None,"c","d",0,1,False,0,1,0,3,[],0,1,9,0,0,{},0,0,9]

for x in a:
    if x == 0:
        a.remove(x)
        count += 1

print(a, count)
```

Only 6 out of 10 zeros are removed. Why ?

Comment: please always use the generic [python] tag for all python questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A far better solution is to just create a new list that does not contain the 0s:

```
b = [x for x in a if x != 0]
count = len(a) - len(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

To workaround the issue described by the guys in comments you can do the following:

```py
count = 0
a = ["a",0,0,"b",None,"c","d",0,1,False,0,1,0,3,[],0,1,9,0,0,{},0,0,9]
for x in a.copy():
    if x == 0:
        a.remove(x)
        count += 1
print(a, count)
```

Then you will be iterating through the original `a`, while simultaneously reducing it by `0` whenever you encounter it.

Caveat:

```py
>>> False == 0
True
```

Comment: So I need to make a duplicate list in order to modify one on the fly.

Comment: Correct, if it's "in use" - and you still want to iterate through it, while simultaneously changing it - then yes - you need to duplicate it

Comment: @mr_incredible: another option is to go through it backwards. But duplicating or re-creating it is faster, more readable, less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ["a",0,0,"b",None,"c","d",0,1,False,0,1,0,3,[],0,1,9,0,0,{},0,0,9]

list(filter(lambda a: a != 0, x))
```

output

```
['a', 'b', None, 'c', 'd', 1, 1, 3, [], 1, 9, {}, 9]
```